# How do I use define_method to create class methods?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, class-method

This is useful if you are trying to create class methods metaprogramatically:

```
def self.create_methods(method_name)
    # To create instance methods:
    define_method method_name do
      ...
    end

    # To create class methods that refer to the args on create_methods:
    ???
end
```

My answer to follow...

Answer (score 211, accepted):

I think in Ruby 1.9 you can do this:

```
class A
  define_singleton_method :loudly do |message|
    puts message.upcase
  end
end

A.loudly "my message"

# >> MY MESSAGE
```

Comment: also `singleton_class.define_method`

Comment: @Pyro Just to clarify, would you just go `singleton_class.define_method :loudly do |message|` etc.?

Answer (score 25):

I prefer using send to call define_method, and I also like to create a metaclass method to access the metaclass:

```
class Object
  def metaclass
    class << self
      self
    end
  end
end

class MyClass
  # Defines MyClass.my_method
  self.metaclass.send(:define_method, :my_method) do
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks!  Definitely there are ways to make this nicer for yourself.  But if you are working on an open source plugin, for example, I think it's nicer not to clog up the namespace with `metaclass`, so it's nice to know the easy, standalone shorthand.

Comment: I decided to go with my original answer.  My understanding is that using send() to access private methods if going away in Ruby 1.9, so that didn't seem like a good thing to use.  Plus if you are defining more than one method, instance_evaling a block is cleaner.

Comment: @Vincent Robert any link which would explain the magic of metaclass method?

Comment: class << self; self; end; simply reopens the class of self (class << self) and then returns that class (self) so actually returning the metaclass of self.

Answer (score 9):

This is the simplest way in Ruby 1.8+:

```
class A
  class << self
    def method_name
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I really like this one. Small, neat, reads well and it's portable.

Of course, you could ask what I'm doing using ruby 1.8 in 2013...

Comment: this doesn't answer the question: it's not metaprogramming and it's not using define_method

Answer (score 9):

To be used in Rails if you want to define class methods dynamically from concern:

```
module Concerns::Testable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do 
    singleton_class.instance_eval do
      define_method(:test) do
        puts 'test'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7):

Derived from: [Jay](http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/10/ruby-defining-class-methods.html) and [Why](http://whytheluckystiff.net/articles/seeingMetaclassesClearly.html), who also provide ways to make this prettier.

```
self.create_class_method(method_name)
  (class << self; self; end).instance_eval do
    define_method method_name do
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

---

***Update***: from VR's contribution below; a more concise method (as long as you're only defining one method this way) that is still standalone:

```
self.create_class_method(method_name)
  (class << self; self; end).send(:define_method, method_name) do
    ...
  end
end
```

but note that using send() to access private methods like define_method() is not necessarily a good idea (my understanding is that it is going away in Ruby 1.9).

Comment: Better (?) alternative may be to put things in a module and then have your create_class_method extend the module onto the class???

See: http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/07/ruby-underuse-of-modules.html

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this without relying on define_method:

```
A.class_eval do
  def self.class_method_name(param)
    puts param
  end
end

A.class_method_name("hello") # outputs "hello" and returns nil
```