# Are Dynamic Class Methods possible in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use define_method to create class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752717/how-do-i-use-define-method-to-create-class-methods)

I am trying to do this:

```
class Foo
  class << self
    def runtime_method(*methods)
      methods.each do |name|
        define_method "self.#{name}" do |*args|
          "dynamic class method #{name.inspect}"
        end
        self.class_eval do
          define_method name do
            "dynamic instance method #{name.inspect}"
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  runtime_method :foo, :bar
end

puts Foo.foo rescue #=> otherwise, undefined method `foo' for Foo:Class (NoMethodError)
puts Foo.new.foo #=> dynamic instance method: :foo
puts Foo.new.bar #=> dynamic instance method: :bar
```

Is there any way to define dynamic class methods in ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand you exactly, but is this what you mean?

```
>> class Foo
>> end
=> nil
>> Foo.blah
NoMethodError: undefined method `blah' for Foo:Class
    from (irb):3
>> 
?> Foo.class.class_eval do
?>   def blah
>>     puts "hello"
>>   end
>> end
=> nil
>> Foo.blah
hello
=> nil
```

Comment: This defines blah on _every_ class.