# attr_accessor inner view

Tags: ruby

i'm so new to Ruby

we can say that `attr_accessor :bark`

is sugar coating for

```
 def bark
    @bark
  end

  def bark=(val)
    @bark = val
  end
```

What would be the same when given multiple parameters 
is it?

```
attr_accessor *args
    args.each { |attr|
     def attr
            @attr
          end

          def attr=(val)
            @attr= val
          end
    }
```

and if so how can i use the same with initialization of all given params also

and in **class_eval**(Meta OOP) with dynamic **attr+random_str**?

Comment: I think you should have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752717/how-do-i-use-define-method-to-create-class-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stuff

```
attr_accessor *args
  args.each { |attr|
   def attr
     @attr
   end

   def attr=(val)
     @attr= val
   end
 }
```

won't work. It would create a method "attr" which returns the value of the instance variable "@attr". I think that's not what you want to do, right? You should do

```
args.each do |arg|
  self.define_singleton_method arg do self.instance_variable_get arg end
end
```

for the getter and almost the same stuff for the setter. 
I don't know what you mean with

> and if so how can i use the same with initialization of all given params also
>   and in class_eval(Meta OOP) with dynamic attr+random_str?

regards