# Why does define_method not create a new class method in this example?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have this code:

```
module Helper
  def translates(*attributes)
    attributes.each do |attribute|
      define_method("find_by_#{attribute}") do |value|
        value
      end  
    end  
  end  
end  

class SomeClass
  extend Helper
  translates :foo
end
```

Now, in my opinion, the method `SomeClass.find_by_foo` should exist. But it doesn't. Do you know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It exists but you defined it as an instance method SomeClass.new.find_by_foo(1)

Comment: Take a look at a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752717/how-do-i-use-define-method-to-create-class-methods

Comment: @Teoulas The questions are similar, but not identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use the Eigenclass

You can define the method as a class method using the eigenclass. For example:

```
module Helper
  def translates(*attributes)
    attributes.each do |attribute|
      define_singleton_method("find_by_#{attribute}") do |value|
        value
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to put `define_method` inside `instance_eval` but it didn't work. I didn't know about this one.

Answer (score 2):

You'll find that `SomeClass.new.respond_to?(:find_by_foo)` returns true. If you want to add the methods to the class side, use `define_singleton_method`.