# Creating class methods from a module

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Given the simple example here:

```
class Base
  @tag = nil 

  def self.tag(v = nil) 
    return @tag unless v 
    @tag = v
  end 
end 

class A < Base 
  tag :A
end

class B < Base
  tag :B
end 

class C < Base; end

puts "A: #{A.tag}"
puts "B: #{B.tag}"
puts "A: #{A.tag}"
puts "C: #{C.tag}"
```

which works as expected

```
A: A
B: B 
A: A
C:
```

I want to create a module that base will extend to give the same functionality but with all the tag information specified by the class. Eg.

```
module Tester 
  def add_ident(v); ....; end
end

class Base 
  extend Tester 

  add_ident :tag
end
```

I've found i can do it with a straight eval, so:

```
def add_ident(v)
  v = v.to_s 
  eval "def self.#{v}(t = nil); return @#{v} unless t; @#{v} = t; end"
end
```

but i really dislike using eval string in any language.

Is there a way that i can get this functionality without using eval? I've gone through every combination of define_method and instance_variable_get/set i can think of and i can't get it to work.

Ruby 1.9 without Rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to define a dynamic method on the singleton class of the class you're extending. The singleton class of a class can be accessed with expression like this: `class << self; self end`. To open the scope of a class's class, you can use `class_eval`. Putting all this together, you can write:

```
module Identification

  def add_identifier(identifier)
    (class << self; self end).class_eval do
      define_method(identifier) do |*args|
        value = args.first
        if value
          instance_variable_set("@#{identifier}", value)
        else
          instance_variable_get("@#{identifier}")
        end
      end
    end
  end

end

class A
  extend Identification

  add_identifier :tag
end
```

If you're using recent versions of Ruby, this approach can be replaced with [Module#define_singleton_method](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/define_singleton_method):

```
module Identification

  def add_identifier(identifier)
    define_singleton_method(identifier) do |value = nil|
      if value
        instance_variable_set("@#{identifier}", value)
      else
        instance_variable_get("@#{identifier}")
      end
    end
  end

end
```

I don't believe you want to use `self.class.send(:define_method)`, as shown in another answer here; this has the unintended side effect of adding the dynamic method to all child classes of  `self.class`, which in the case of `A` in my example is `Class`.

Answer (score 1):

```
module Tester
  def add_ident(var)
    self.class.send(:define_method, var) do |val=nil|
        return instance_variable_get("@#{var}") unless val
        instance_variable_set "@#{var}", val
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: I suppose it defines method for `Module`.

Answer (score 1):

My favourite ruby book [Metaprogramming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby) solved these questions like the following way:

```
module AddIdent 
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods    # hook method
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def add_ident(tag)
      define_method "#{tag}=" do |value=nil|
        instance_variable_set("@#{tag}", value)
      end

      define_method tag do 
        instance_variable_get "@#{tag}"
      end 
    end
  end
end 

# And use it like this
class Base
  include AddIdent

  add_ident :tag
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Bah isn't it always the way that once you get frustrated enough to post you then find the answer :)

The trick seems to be in (class << self; self; end) to give you the class instance without destroying the local scope. Referencing: [How do I use define_method to create class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752717/how-do-i-use-define-method-to-create-class-methods)

```
def add_ident(v) 
  var_name = ('@' + v.to_s).to_sym 
  (class << self; self; end).send(:define_method, v) do |t = nil|
    return instance_variable_get(var_name) unless t
    instance_variable_set(var_name, t)
  end 
end
```

I'll accept better answers if them come along though.