# Get class variable from class directly

Tags: ruby

Following module:

```
class EnvParams
  def self.mailer
    environment.mailer
  end

  def self.router
    environment.router
  end

  def self.sms_gateway
    environment.sms_gateway
  end

  private

  def self.environment
    @@env ||= Hashie::Mash.new({data: {
        mailer: {
            address: ENV['DISP_MAILER_SERVER'],
            domain: ENV['DISP_MAILER_DOMAIN'],
            port: ENV['DISP_MAILER_PORT'],
            user_name: ENV['DISP_MAILER_USERNAME'],
            password: ENV['DISP_MAILER_PASSWORD'],
            sender: ENV['DISP_MAILER_SENDER']
        },
        router: {
            url: ENV['GTC_ROUTER_URL']
        },
        sms_gateway: {
            url: ENV['SMS_GATEWAY_URL']
        }
    }}).data
  end
end
```

had been created to concentrate all references to environment variables in one file and is intended to be queried for environment variables in such manner:

```
EnvParams.mailer.password
```

What I do not like is a bunch of `def self.mailer`, `def self.router`, `def self.sms_gateway` getters - one for each section. If a new section appears, a new getter has to be defined. How to avoid this without having to call an intermediate getter like `EnvParams.environment.mailer.password` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Forwardable` is a better solution, but to provide another option, you could dynamically create the methods:

```
class A
  def self.method_missing(name, *args, &blk)
    define_singleton_method name.to_sym do 
      environment.send(name.to_sym)
    end 
    self.send(name.to_sym)
  end
end
```

I found my inspiration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752717/how-do-i-use-define-method-to-create-class-methods).  This is works on Ruby 1.9.

Comment: Wonderful! There is something to enhance here: to throw a `NoMethodError` exception if `@@env` does not contain a requested name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use delegators from Forwardable module ( http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html )

```
class EnvParams
  extend Forwardable

  def_delegator :environment, :mailer
end
```